# Build a half cardinal cyclic quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

A half cardinal cyclic quine is a cyclic quine with two states, one perpendicular to the other.

### Rules

You can decide which rotation you want to implement, clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Once rotated, any gaps in your code should be replaced with spaces to preserve the positioning.

Your program must satisfy [the community definition of a quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/9365).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest program in each language wins. Your *first* program is used for your byte count.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden.

### Examples

If your program is:

```
$_='print';eval
```

Then the next iteration must be either:

```
$
_
=
'
p
r
i
n
t
'
;
e
v
a
l
```

or

```
l
a
v
e
;
'
t
n
i
r
p
'
=
_
$
```

which must output the original program:

```
$_='print';eval
```

If your program is:

```
;$_=';
;$_=';
print
```

Then the next iteration must be either:

```
;;
''t
==n
__i
$$r
;;p
```

or:

```
p;;
r$$
i__
n==
t''
 ;;
```

which must output the original program:

```
;$_=';
;$_=';
print
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156129/9365).

Comment: [Somewhat related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73301/8478)

Comment: So, we pad the code with spaces to keep its shape after turning?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, I'll confirm that in the body, thanks! I've also clarified that the first program is the byte-count used.

Comment: Is the only difference between this and the post @MartinEnder linked that that is a transpose and this is a rotation?

Comment: @dylnan No, the other one doesn't ask for a mutual quine.

Comment: Having seen the answers so far I think the real challenge would be the anticlockwise one or a quine with more than one lines (so that rotation is different from transposition or simply inserting newlines).

Comment: @WeijunZhou Indeed, I'm not sure how feasible it is, but I have a [more complex version of this in the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14855/9365).

Comment: Are the quine and its rotation allowed to be the same?

Comment: You might want to require the two programs to be different. Otherwise, quines which happen to have rotational symmetry would be valid answers.

Comment: And the same applies to the one in the sandbox

Comment: I really want to see an answer in Python, even if it has symmetry. I'm getting stuck

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm not sure I feel the programs have to be different, I think a quine that can be rotated would be valid as I feel that might be a challenge on its own. Does that help you compete (not really I'm guessing, by the last comment!), I would love to see a Python solution!

Comment: I sure hope no lovely red birds are going to be harmed in the course of this contest...

Comment: I think another interesting scoring method would be `max(width, height) ** 2`, so getting your program to be more square would be incentivized.

Comment: @mbomb007 I quite like that... Perhaps a challenge to create a quine that is the same when rotated 90° using that scoring mechanism?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
{s"_~"+N*""-}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7pYKb5OSdtPS0lJtza@7v9/AA) [Try the rotation.](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v5qrmEuJK56rDkhqc/lxaQFpJS5drlqQ2P//AA)

#### Explanation

```
{s"_~"+  e# Standard quine framework. Puts a string representation of the entire
         e# program on the stack.
  N*     e# Riffle linefeeds into the string, which is effectively a clockwise
         e# rotation by 90°.
  ""-    e# Does nothing.
}_~
```

In the rotated code, we've got linefeeds everywhere:

```
{
s
"
_
~
"
+
N
*
"
"
-
}
_
~
```

As [Lynn noticed on Dom's earlier quine challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156142/8478) inserting linefeeds actually still forms valid quine, because the linefeeds inside the block will just be retained verbatim anyway, and there will also be linefeeds in the `"_~"` string to make those two characters at the end show up on their own line. So `{s"_~"+...}_~` (with linefeeds) is still a valid quine framework (although there'll be an additional linefeed at the end of the string). `N*` now inserts even more linefeeds into that string, but we don't really care: because now `""-` has a linefeed inside that string so it actually removes all linefeeds from the program representation. So we end up with the horizontal form of the code again, undoing the rotation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 28 bytes

```
"8H^Hs+2*A]/Mm"8H^Hs+2*A]/Mm
```

[Run and debug the first form](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%228H%5EHs%2B2*A%5D%2FMm%228H%5EHs%2B2*A%5D%2FMm&i=&a=1)

[Run and debug the second form](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22%0A8%0AH%0A%5E%0AH%0As%0A%2B%0A2%0A*%0AA%0A%5D%0A%2F%0AM%0Am%0A%22%0A8%0AH%0A%5E%0AH%0As%0A%2B%0A2%0A*%0AA%0A%5D%0A%2F%0AM%0Am&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 bytes

```
 "2+}>oao#ov*48}}*d3'v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0HJSLvWLj8xXzm/TMvEorZWK8VYvez/fwA)

Rotated anti-clockwise:

```
v
'
3
d
*
}
}
8
4
*
v
o
#
o
a
o
>
}
+
2
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v4xLncuYK4VLi6sWCC24TICsMq58LmUgTgRiO6CoNpcRlxLX//8A)

The first one prints the line in reverse with newlines interspersed, and the second prints it in reverse without the newlines.

Comment: This is very clever!

Comment: Good going on approaching it on hard mode!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
4"D6Ø·çýD¶åi¶KëS»"D6Ø·çýD¶åi¶KëS»
```

[Try first iteration](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fRMnF7PCMQ9sPLz@81@XQtsNLMw9t8z68OvjQbpwSXP//AwA)
or [Try next iteration](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fhEuJy4XLjOvwDK5D27kOL@c6vBfIP7SN6/BSrkwQ7c11eDVXMNeh3cQr/P8fAA)